# how to get particular user content using $http in ionic

Tags: javascript

i am new to ionic. I have populated user list successfully with rest call.
I want to get users particular data using $http method. but i am unable to do it.here is my code.

service.js

```
angular.module('starter.service',[]).
  factory('Contents',['$http',function($http){
    var users = [];

    return {
      get: function(){
        return $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(function(response){
          users = response;
          return users;
        });
      },
      remove:function(content){
        users.splice(users.indexOf(content),1);
      },
      getUser:function(chatId)
      {
        console.log('inside service');
        for(var i=0; i<users.length;i++){
          if(users[i].id === parseInt(chatId)){
            return users[i];

          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
  }]);
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controller', [])


  .controller('ChatCtrl', function($scope, Contents,$ionicModal) {
     console.log('inside controller');
    Contents.get().then(function(users){
      //users is an array of user objects
      $scope.contents=users.data;
      console.log($scope.contents);
    });
      $scope.remove = function(content) {
      Contents.remove(content);

    };

  })
  .controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Contents) {
    console.log('details');



$scope.content = Contents.getUser($stateParams.chatId);

    console.log($stateParams.chatId);
    console.log($scope.content)
});
```

chat.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Chats">

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="content in contents" type="item-text-wrap" >
          <img  ng-src="{{content.image}}" style="width:50px; height:50px;" ng-click="showUser(content)">
        <a href="#/tab/chats/{{content.id}}" class="subdued">
        <h2>{{content.name}}</h2>
          <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
          <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(content)">
            Delete
          </ion-option-button>
</a>
       </ion-item>

      </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This chat.html redirect to another template called chat-detail.html which display user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you cannot remove a user. That is happening because you are not removing from the users array (which is in response.data) but from the response itself (which you stored in your users variable for some reason).

Here is something that should help you:

This is in your service

```
angular.module('starter.service', [])
  .factory('Contents', ['$http', function($http) {
    var users = [];

    return {
      get: function(){
        return $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
          .then(function(response) {
            users = response.data;
            return users;
          });
      },
      ...
  }]);
```

And this in your controller

```
angular.module('starter.controller', [])  
  .controller('ChatCtrl', function($scope, Contents, $ionicModal) {
    console.log('inside controller');
    Contents.get().then(function(users){
      //users is an array of user objects
      $scope.contents = users;
      console.log($scope.contents);
    });

    $scope.remove = function(content) {
      Contents.remove(content);
    };
  })
  .controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Contents) {
    console.log('details');
    $scope.content = Contents.getUser($stateParams.chatId);

    console.log($stateParams.chatId);
    console.log($scope.content)
  });
```

Also, I didn't rename anything so you'd understand what I have modified, but here are some modifications you might want to do:

- Rename Contents to something like 'userService'
- Use camelCase everywhere (except the controller name)
- Pay more attention to variable names (or $scope properties) because something called contents which actually contains users is not really good.

Hope this helps, tell me if not.

Comment: If this helped please mark the answer as correct. Glad I could help!